# loop over tree like structure

Tags: python, tree, iteration, generator

I've this kind of structure:

```
[
    array([ 0. ,  4.5,  9. ]),
    [
        array([ 100.,  120.,  140.]),
        [
            array([ 1000.,  1100.,  1200.]), 
            array([ 1200.,  1300.,  1400.])
        ],
        array([ 150.,  170.,  190.]),
        [
            array([ 1500.,  1600.,  1700.]), 
            array([ 1700.,  1800.])
        ]
    ]
]
```

(where `array`s are `numpy.array`s)

how to write a generator that give me:

```
(0, 4.5), (100, 120), (1000, 1100)
(0, 4.5), (100, 120), (1100, 1200)
(0, 4.5), (120, 140), (1200, 1300)
(0, 4.5), (120, 140), (1300, 1400)
(4.5, 9), (150, 170), (1500, 1600)
(4.5, 9), (150, 170), (1600, 1700)
(4.5, 9), (170, 190), (1700, 1800)
```

by now, the only thig I have is:

```
def loop_bin(bins):
    for i in range(len(bins)-1):
        yield [bins[i], bins[i+1]]
```

Comment: What is *array*? Why is line 3 and 4 identical?

Comment: Are you aware of itertools? http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html

Comment: @CraigWright: yes, but this doesn't help me

Comment: Are there always three elements in each of the arrays?

Comment: @CraigWright: no, only in this example

Comment: If this example is not representative, please describe exactly what wou want, i.e. for array([1,2,3,4]), produce (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)? Do the sublists always contain two or four elements?

Comment: Maybe you can use `yield from`, brand new in Python 3.3? [PEP description](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
def foo(m):

  for i in range(0, len(m), 2):

    for j in range(len(m[i])-1):
      current = tuple(m[i][j:(j+2)])
      mm = m[i+1]
      if(len(mm) % 2 != 0 or (len(mm) > 1 and not type(mm[1][0]) is types.ListType)):
        currentl = mm[j]
        for k in range(0, len(currentl)-1):
          yield current, tuple(currentl[k:(k+2)])

      else:
        for res in foo(mm[2*j:2*j+2]):
          # this is for pretty print only
          if type(res) is types.TupleType and len(res)>1 and not type(res[0]) is types.TupleType:
            yield current, res
          else:
            # pretty print again
            c = [current]
            c+= res
            yield tuple(c)
```

The `tuple` things are for pretty print, in order to get closer to your example. I was not very sure on the criteria to use for detecting a leaf. Note also that I made my experiments with the following pythonic array:

```
arr = [
    [ 0. ,  4.5,  9. ],
    [
        [100.,  120.,  140.],
        [
            [ 1000.,  1100.,  1200.], 
            [ 1200.,  1300.,  1400.]
        ],
        [ 150.,  170.,  190.],
        [
            [ 1500.,  1600.,  1700.], 
            [ 1700.,  1800.]
        ]
    ]
]
```

rather than the numpy array given, but the changes to get things running with numarray  should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

looking at your situation i've broken it down into a few different types of iterations: `overlap` and `paired` (as well as regular iteration).

i then recursively traverse your tree structure in `dopair` which analyses the types to decide how it should iterate over the data it sees. the decision is based on whether we are processing a node (which contains a subtree) or a leaf (an array).

`generator` kicks it all off. `izip` allows us to iterate two generators at the same time.

```
from itertools import izip

class array(list):
    pass

arr = [
    array([ 0. ,  4.5,  9. ]),
    [
        array([100.,  120.,  140.]),
        [
            array([ 1000.,  1100.,  1200.]), 
            array([ 1200.,  1300.,  1400.])
        ],
        array([ 150.,  170.,  190.]),
        [
            array([ 1500.,  1600.,  1700.]), 
            array([ 1700.,  1800.])
        ]
    ]
]

# overlap(structure) -> [st, tr, ru, uc, ct, tu, ur, re]
def overlap(structure):
    for i in range(len(structure)-1):
        yield (structure[i],structure[i+1])

# paired(structure) -> [st, ru, ct, ur]
def paired(structure):
    for i in range(0,len(structure)-1,2):
        yield (structure[i],structure[i+1])

def dopair(first,second):
    if all(isinstance(x,array) for x in second): 
        for pa,ir in izip(overlap(first),second):
            for item in overlap(ir):
                yield pa, item
    else:
        for pa,(i,r) in izip(overlap(first),paired(second)):
            for item in dopair(i,r):
                yield (pa,) + item

def generator(arr):
    for pa,ir in paired(arr):
        for x in dopair(pa,ir):
            yield x

for x in generator(arr):
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion to do it:

```
def foo( lst, path ):
    if type(lst[0]) != type(array([])):
        return [path+[(lst[0],lst[1])], path+[(lst[1],lst[2])]]

    i = 0
    ret = []
    while i < len(lst):
        node = lst[i]
        successor = lst[i+1] if i+1<len(lst) else None
        if type(node) == type(array([])):
            if type(successor) == list:
                children = successor
                ret.extend( foo( children, path + [(node[0], node[1])] ) )
                ret.extend( foo( children, path + [(node[1], node[2])] ) )
                i+=1
            else:
                ret.append( path + [(node[0], node[1])] )
                ret.append( path + [(node[1], node[2])] )
        i+=1
    return ret
```

Call `foo( input, [] )` to calculate.

Comment: This produces 32 items instead of just 8.